# jQuery: Follow cursor with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove

I want a div to follow the cursor-movement with a short delay like this: http://vanderlanth.io/

As you can see, the 'follower' has a short delay in the animation.

I've rebuild some function which is not working very well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").mousemove(function (e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });

    function handleMouseMove(event) {

        var x = event.pageX;
        var y = event.pageY;

        $(".cursor-follower").animate({
            left: (x - 16),
            top: (y - 16)
        }, 16);

        $(".cursor").css({
            left: (x - 4),
            top: (y - 4)
        });
    }
});
```

It's quite lagging and the animation is not very smooth and ease. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Without looking at the site you posted, I'm guessing it's one of those continuous transitions with an easing function from the 2000s.

Comment: It is not a delay that is being used. It is just an easing function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with CSS transitions. In JavaScript you only have to update the position of the div.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', (event) => {
  $('.follower').css({
    left: event.clientX,
    top: event.clientY,
  });
});
```

```css
.follower {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="follower"></div>
```

Comment: `.follower` transform property can be simplified to: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: This stutters on Safari, is there a workaround we can use instead?