# Refactoring a jQuery code to angular code for a magic cursor effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

Below is the code for the magic cursor effect. But I'm struggling to get the same effect in Angular.

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var coordinateX=0;
            var coordinateY=0;
            var bottomCursor=document.querySelector('.circle-cursor-bottom');
            var topCursor=document.querySelector('.circle-cursor-top');


            function displayCursor(e){
                document.addEventListener('mousemove',e=>{
                coordinateX=e.clientX;
                coordinateY=e.clientY
            });


            function animCursor(){
                    topCursor.style.transform=`translate(${coordinateX}px, ${coordinateY}px)`;
                    bottomCursor.style.transform=`translate(${coordinateX}px, ${coordinateY}px)`;
            requestAnimationFrame(animCursor)};
            requestAnimationFrame(animCursor)};
            displayCursor();
        
        });
```

```css
.circle-cursor {
  position:fixed;
  pointer-events:none;
  width:1.4376rem;
  height:1.4376rem;
  margin:-0.630rem 0 0 -0.630px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-radius:50%;   
}
.circle-cursor-inner {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   border-radius:50%;
   display:block;
}
.circle-cursor-top {
   background-color:#22d4b5;
   transition:transform 0.06s cubic-bezier(.12,.12,.25,.92),opacity 1s ease;
   z-index:9999;
}
.circle-cursor-bottom {
  background:#6edddf;
  transition:transform 0.26s cubic-bezier(.12,.12,.25,.92),opacity 1s ease;
  z-index:9998;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-cursor-holder">
  <div class="circle-cursor   circle-cursor-top">
    <span class="circle-cursor-inner"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-cursor circle-cursor-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

This is the code I tried. But not able to replicate with precision. Any Idea/Best way to implement would be helpful.

```
<div class="custom-cursor-holder">
  <div #top class="circle-cursor   circle-cursor-top">
    <span class="circle-cursor-inner"></span>
  </div>
  <div #bottom class="circle-cursor circle-cursor-bottom"></div>
</div>

export class AppComponent{
  coordinateX = 0;
  coordinateY = 0;

  @ViewChild('top') top!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('bottom') bottom!: ElementRef;

  /**
   *
   */
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }

  @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event'])
  onOver(event: MouseEvent): void {
      this.coordinateX = event.clientX;
      this.coordinateY = event.clientY;
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.top.nativeElement, 'transform', 'translate('+ this.coordinateX +'px, '+ this.coordinateY +'px)');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158183/angular-follow-cursor-has-too-much-delay-lag/73162811#73162811)

Using `fromEvent(document,'mousemove')` and throttleTime rxjs/operator

```
  @ViewChild('top') top!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('bottom') bottom!: ElementRef;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.subscription=fromEvent(document,'mousemove').pipe(throttleTime(50,asyncScheduler,{ leading:true,trailing: true })).subscribe((e:any)=>{
      const coordinateX=e.clientX;
      const coordinateY=e.clientY;
      this.top.nativeElement.style.transform=
               `translate(${coordinateX}px, ${coordinateY}px)`;
      this.bottom.nativeElement.style.transform=
               `translate(${coordinateX}px, ${coordinateY}px)`;
    })
  }
  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

a [stackbltiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-189un8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: it's neccesary use throttleTime to give a breath to Angular